# Anyone know what kind of unicode is this with &# and semicolon please? how to turn it into chinese characters string in Python please?

Tags: python, unicode

I have these symbols which I am quite sure they are chinese characters.

```
&#26053;&#34892;&#26178;&#65292;&#25105;&#29983;&#30149;
```

Please anyone know what kind of unicode is this with &# and semicolon please? And how can I turn it into chinese characters string or normal unicode in Python please?

Comment: Those are HTML entities.

Comment: `import html; html.unescape(inputstring)`; this produces `'旅行時，我生病'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so much thanks!!!

Comment: I've already duplicated your post to the canonical.

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-unified-ideographs/